# Concurrently generate many matplotlib figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, concurrency

I want to generate a large number (`N`) of PDF plots using `matpotlib`.
Each plot requires reading the contents of a variable `x` without modifying it.
When `N` is too large the code takes ages to finish.
Is it possible to speed things up using some flavor of concurrency
(e.g., by sending the job to generate each PDF to a different thread)?

```
from pylab import *

N = 1000
x = linspace(0,100,10001)

for n in range(N):
    fig = figure()
    plot(x,sin(x/(n+1)))
    savefig(f'{n+1}.pdf')
    close(fig)
```

Comment: With multiprocessing you can speed things up by a factor < k, where k is the number of cores of your computer. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure if reading the same variable (x) from different processes/threads is possible?